# PID in case of irq context

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, irq, softirq

what does "current->pid" prints in below 2 case

1) Hard IRQ context

2) Soft IRQ context

I know IRQ context and process context are different, and PID must be invalid in case of IRQ context. But when try to print "current->pid" in IRQ context it is printing some valid PID, hence got the doubt.
Please clarify.

Thank You,

Gopinath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shows just a pid of a process that the IRQ preepmts.

You can imagine that:

1. A process whose pid is 1001 is running.
2. At that time, you press a key to raise an IRQ.
3. The IRQ handler preempts the process whose `current->pid` is 1001.

There is ***NO RELATIONSHIP*** between `current->pid` and the IRQ